# How to achieve Single Sign-Out in Keycloak/Spring based applications?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, keycloak

I have 2 Spring web-apps. I'm using Keycloak to protect them. In Keycloak doc it's said that to logout i can use:

```
HttpServletRequest.logout()
```

Yes, it loges out user from one app. But the second one still remains active. How to configure Keycloak and/or Spring to provide Single Sign Out?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Spring Security adapter use the [`/sso/logout` endpoint](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/c8c76cc03fba2084cd7993ff0506020e8bb6613d/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/config/KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java#L134) instead (either in GET or POST). For instance:

```
http://myapplication/sso/logout
```